# Inserting in order (linked list C) error

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote the function below to insert a value in order into the linked list, using a cmp function defined by the user. So i tested this out, I wrote my own cmp function for integers, and put in the values 9 and 1. The output was 9 and 1 (it did not insert into the linked list in order). After debugging this function for a while, I figured that if(prev == NULL) is never true, hence my program is breaking, is there anything I am doing wrong here???, we can compare to NULL right?

```
list_t *insert_in_order(list_t *list, void *value, int (*cmp)(void*,void*)) {

    node_t *new_node, *curr, *prev;
    new_node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    assert(new_node != NULL && list != NULL);
    new_node->data = value;

    /*Special case when the list is empty*/

    if(list->head == NULL) {

        new_node->next = NULL;
        list->head = list->foot = new_node;

    }

    /*List is obviously not empty*/     

    else {

        curr = list->head;
        prev = NULL;

        /*Traverse the list*/
        while(curr) {

        /*I am basically going to break the loop when I find the right position*/
        /*to insert the node (after this node called prev)*/

            if(cmp(curr->data, value) > 0) {
                break;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        /*So now I know the node will go after the prev (defined above) node.*/

       /*Special case if this is the 0th position in the linked list i.e prev is null*/

        if(prev == NULL) {
            /*After doing some printfs here I see that prev is never null, anything*/
            /*wrong here???????????*/
            printf("prev is null\n");
            new_node->next = list->head;
            list->head = new_node;
        }

        else {
            printf("prev is not null\n");
            new_node->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = new_node;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just debug using `printf`, why not debug using a debugger? Step through the code, line by line, to see what *really* happens.

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that your cmp() function is broken. Can you print the result of the cmp function an ensure it's working as you intend? It's the only way I can see that you are getting the problem you describe.

Comment: int cmp(void *a, void *b) {
 int *ad = a, *bd = b;
 if(ad < bd) 
  return -1;
 else if(ad > bd)
  return 1;
 else 
  return 0;

}

Comment: You haven't dereferenced ad and bd there.

Comment: Ah, you are comparing the pointers, not the values. You should have; if(*ad < *bd), etc as ad is an "int *"

Comment: Omg i am so embarassed, thanks so much it worked! Forgot the dereference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert in this code snippet

```
else {
    printf("prev is not null\n");
    new_node->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = new_node;
```

the following statement

```
else {
    printf("prev is not null\n");
    new_node->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = new_node;
    if ( new_node->next == NULL ) list->foot = new_node;
```

The other problem can be realted to the parameter `value`. It should be always allocated in the heap anew. You may not pass an address of the same local variable with different values. So the code should look for example as

```
int *p = ( int * )malloc( sizeof( int ) );
*p = 9;

insert_in_order( list, p, cmp );

p = ( int * )malloc( sizeof( int ) );
*p = 1;

insert_in_order( list, p, cmp );
```

Or you have to allocated a copy of the passed value in the function.

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I had made a mistake in my cmp function, i didn't dereference the values before comparing them. But the parameter value, I stored it in an array, and I passed the address of the corresponding element. So I think that part is fine. Thanks =D